# (Angular Ui-Grid) When cell is filtering enable and date is formatted the search is incorrect

Tags: angular, angular-ui-grid

I'm using UI-GRID in a nice table with several values.
This grid has a date column with a custom format dd/MM/yyyy (the original value is a longdate in USA standard format)

When you'll search in this column using a custom format (i.e 25/08/2017) UI-GRID has no rows to display.
But, when try using a longdate format, the filter works fine.

I think this is an issue (already have open an issue in GH).

My code:

```
 case 'DATA':
              displayName = 'Data Proposta';
              width = (columns[item].name.length / 1.1);
              cellFilter = 'date:\'dd/MM/yyyy\'';
              break;
 case 'VALIDADE':
              displayName = 'Validade';
              width = (columns[item].name.length / 1.6);
              cellFilter = 'date:\'dd/MM/yyyy\'';
              break;
```

Besides, there's any temporary solution to this?

Tks in advance!

Comment: No response from UI-GRID devs yet. Maybe thinking in use a custom filter instead.